# Symfony doctrine had an sql injection failure?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, sql-injection

I made a little project in symfony 3, and ran the detectify.com over that.
As detectify says, i have "Blind SQL Injection in MySQL" risk

I have Postgres, but nevermind. My keys in the table escalated to 700 after scan. But no data here.
Sooo, i have a security risk.

the controller:

```
public function bidAction($category = null, Request $request)
{

    $bid = new Bids();
    $bid->setCategory($category);
    $bid->setDate(new \DateTime('now'));

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($bid)
        ->add('notes', 'textarea', array('label' => 'Message'))
        ->add('email', 'email')
        ->add('save', 'submit', array('label' => 'Write your bid'))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid() && $form->isSubmitted()) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($bid);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirectToRoute('mikola_studio_main_bid_category', array('category'=>'success'));
    }

    return $this->render('MikolaStudioMainBundle:Default:bid.html.twig',
        array(
            'category' => $category,
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'unique'=>false, // for template
            'sidebar'=>true  // for template
        ));
}
```

i was in faith, doctrine persist were protected against sql injection
im now disappointed

the entity:

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="notes", type="text")
 */
private $notes;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Assert\Email(
 *     message = "The ({{ value }}) is not valid!",
 *     checkMX = true
 * )
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $email;
```

Twig:

```
                    {{ form_start(form) }}
                    {{ form_errors(form) }}

                    {{ form_row(form.notes) }}
                    {{ form_row(form.email) }}

                    <footer>{{ form_row(form.save, {'attr': {'class': 'button icon fa-shopping-cart'}}) }}</footer>
                    {{ form_end(form) }}
```

The detectify request body:

```
form%5Bnotes%5D=&form%5Bemail%5D=If(%40x%2c0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1))‌​)%2f*%27Or(If(%40x%2c0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1))))Or%27%22or(If(%40x%2c‌​0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1))))Or%22*%2f&form%5Bsave%5D=
```

readable:

```
form[notes]=&form[email]=If(@x,0,(SeleCT(@x:=SleeP(0.1)--1))‌​)/*'Or(If(@x,0,(SeleCT(@x:=SleeP(0.1)--1))))Or'"or(If(@x,‌​0,(SeleCT(@x:=SleeP(0.1)--1))))Or"*/&form[save]=
```

[image]

Comment: SQL injection is a serious matter, but I think you've got a false positive here. If you don’t mess things up in your application code (e.g. posting raw SQL queries with unescaped payload), Doctrine is pretty secure by default. I don't know this `detectify.com` service, but there are lots of such services, and most of them are well described with the term “scareware”. Anyway, does the warning indicate which particular portions of Doctrine/Symfony are at risk? Does the tool reveal the exact attack vector?

Comment: nope, doesnt said.
but in my DB table, i see, the new records do not start at the normal id (auto increment)
they start at +700 !! o.0
so i think detectify can write 700 records (not a big stuff), and can delete them! (this is a big stuff)

Comment: Request body:

form%5Bnotes%5D=&form%5Bemail%5D=If(%40x%2c0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1)))%2f*%27Or(If(%40x%2c0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1))))Or%27%22or(If(%40x%2c0%2c(SeleCT(%40x%3a%3dSleeP(0.1)--1))))Or%22*%2f&form%5Bsave%5D=

Comment: The detectify website says you get an easy to understand report.  Please update your question with the actual report.  And move the request body stuff to your question as well so it is readable.

Comment: @Mikopet: Can you try "replaying" the attack? What results does this give you? Any error or success messages?

Comment: Neither your "request" or your pretty graph make much sense to me.  Could you post a link to the source code for your "little project"?

Comment: @lxg: I tried, but the error is found at the most time (not always ~80%)

Comment: @Cerad: all what we need is in OP. And the practice is all from the symfony cookbook. :/

Comment: @Mikopet: When I said “replaying”, I meant that you should try to perform the attack yourself and try to get an error message, then post it here. All of the information you've posted so far is pretty much useless to solve the problem, because it doesn't help us to understand which of the internals are affected and cause the error report. (And, honestly, I still think it's a false positive.)

Comment: @lxg i cant, beacuse i have not enough skill or knowledge to do that.
but i dont think it is false positive, beacuse the detectify delete from my db without permission o.0